# acer aspire 5102WLMi turning off

Tags: acer-aspire

I got this laptop to reinstall windows xp on it because it was working too slowly. Soo after I finally made it to backup all the data, which took like million hours to get those 100GB via LAN, and formated the hard drive. Then I started with the installation itself but when coyping installation data somewhere around 80% the laptop just turned off. So i tried it a couple more times with the same result just with differing percentage. Once, it finally made it to desired 100 but then it turned off when came to that other part of the installation with that screen worshiping new version of windows. It doesn't matter if the battery is in or out, nor does the adapter connection change anything.

any ideas?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/206417/ubuntu-10-10-running-on-acer-aspire-5315-laptop-keeps-shutting-down-unexpectedly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the Power connector is working / fitted properly.
On certain older Laptops they used a strange star shaped spring on the power connector to hold the adaptor in place when you plugged it into the laptop, try making sure that there is power going in constantly and not just for a bit and then stopping?
I would imagine that the temperature is the culprit here though, one way to test is to leave the LT for a while to completely cool down and then power it on, continue until failiure and then immediately power it on again. Does it last longer when starting from cold? If so then heat is definitely the most likely cause.

Comment: It takes a bit longer if starting from cold, but it won't last more than 20min, maybe not even that. What's the most likely component suffering from the heat?

Comment: Its most likely the CPU, although many components can be damaged by heat, chipset and GPU's can suffer from the heat as can HDD's.
I would check to see if the ventilation ports on your LT are clear of dust, if you are experienced and confident / competent then perhaps look inside to check if there is a large dust buildup on the heatsink. 
This wikipedia page might help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cooling

Comment: Glad to hear its helped.

Answer (score 0):

What about the laptop's temperature? If it is way too hot, it can turn itself off to prevent damage.

Do you have any additional information like error logs or error messages?

Comment: That's what I thought as well but, I don't think it's too hot, the fan is working quite fast though. The bios that currently is on the laptop doesn't have any temperature managment features anyway...

No error messages occured anywhere during the installation.