# Ubuntu 10.10 running on Acer Aspire 5315 Laptop keeps shutting down unexpectedly

Tags: shutdown, acer-aspire, ubuntu-10.10, sensors

Basically the title says it all - I have an Acer Aspire 5315 laptop on which I've installed 'Ubuntu 10.10 Desktop i386' from a bootable flash drive and while using the system thereafter all seems to be OK for about 15 - 20 minutes when suddenly the laptop will shutdown with absolutely no warning.

At the start of the install I saw a message which said something along the lines of 'Setting sensor limits' or something silmilar - I can't remember the exact wording.

I have had a look at the BIOS settings to see if there was any temperature value there that had been set too low, but didn't see any section dealing with system \ cpu \ ram temperatures, etc.

I am positive that there isn't a hardware fault with the laptop - I have a Windows 7 Home Edition image of the harddrive courtesy of 'Acronis True Image' and when the drive is imaged with it the laptop will stay running for as long as I am using it.

Any help with solving this problem would be appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved via BIOS update to v 1.43

I hope this is of help to somebody :-)

Comment: You can mark your answer as the accepted answer so that this particular question is closed.